# Mix physical media for ESXi VM, or keep it all on one physical volume?

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, ssd

Say I have a 120GB SSD and a 2TB volume from a portion of a larger RAID6 array. I would like to spin up a Windows Server VM for purely low-impact personal use that employs a large data store in some fashion. Which would be a better practice: (a) Separate the OS and data drives, physically, by giving the SSD the C:\ drive and the 2TB RAID the D:\ drive, or (b) place the VM completely within the RAID array and disregard the SSD?

It strikes me that (a) might offer more performance and a negligible space increase while (b) might improve fault tolerance, since the SSD is not backed up in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you got down-voted already but this question does look like "asked and answered" to me.  The key phrase is "low-impact personal use".

Generally you gain little if anything by placing the OS on an SSD.  Server OSes are a lot less "chatty" than desktop OSes, so there's a lot less disk I/O going on.  Ordinarily you would put database transaction logs or any other kind of volume that has a lot of I/O going on and needs the performance onto faster storage.